# Most succinct way to initialise objects in static List

Tags: java

I'm learning Java, coming from C and C#, and wondering if there is not a more succinct way to initialize a static list of objects than is shown below?

Seems like a lot of bother to go to, creating and repeatedly using the constructor of `Part`, for what is essentially a simple struct type.

```
class Widget {

    private static class Part {
        public String number;
        public String description;

        Part(String number, String description)
        {
            // a constructor just to initialize public fields? ugh
            this.number = number;
            this.description = description;
        }
    }

    private static final List<Part> parts = List.of(
        new Part("ABC",  "Doo-hickey"), // < seems overwrought
        new Part("DEF",  "whadjamacalit"),
        new Part("HIJ",  "thing-a-ma-bob"),
        // ...
    );

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You could put your strings into arrays and create the parts in a loop.

Comment: If you don't plan to modify the list at runtime, you could use an `Enum`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm learning Java, coming from C and C#, and wondering if there is not
>   a more succinct way to initialize a static list of objects than is
>   shown below?

There are some alternatives of similar verbosity, but inasmuch as your primary objection seems to be to the use of the `new` operator and the attending repetition of the class name, no, there is no way to avoid these or an equivalent.  In particular, Java has no direct analog of C-style initializers for objects of compound type.

You'll have noted that I left a bit of wiggle room for "equivalents" in place of using specifically `new` and a constructor.  What's in fact required is simply an expression of appropriate type that can be evaluated in static context.  The most notable alternatives to using the `new` operator would be an invocation of a suitable static method or an invocation of an instance method of a statically-accessible object.

> Seems like a lot of bother to go to, creating and repeatedly using the
>   constructor of Part, for what is essentially a simple struct type.

Java does not distinguish between different flavors of reference types in this way.  In fact, although you define no methods for your class `Part`, it still has those it inherits from `Object`, and in that sense it is not analogous to a "simple struct type" in the sense I think you mean.

Note also that a `List<Part>` can contain instances of subclasses of `Part`, so from the localized perspective of the Java compiler, it is not clear that every element should be specifically of class `Part`.  Java could conceivably take that as an assumption, but it's simpler not to do so.  The few extra characters are not a big deal from my perspective.

Answer (score 2):

You're perhaps thinking of doing something like from C#:

```
new List<Part> {
    new {"ABC", "Doo-hickey"},
    new {"DEF", "whadjamacalit"}
}
```

That's not possible in Java, which is a pain when initializing larger objects. You could get away with a factory method attached to `Part`. Something like `Part.make("ABC", "Doo-hickey")`. It won't save you typing in this case, but perhaps in more complicated cases.